# Deselect items in Listview (windows store app)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a ListView named _criteria, populated with 5 items.  ListView SelectionMode="Multiple"

When each item is selected, I want to increment the int count by 1, which I can do here in the _crit Selection Changed event handler:

```
    private void _crit(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        textBox1.Text = "this is "+count;
    }
```

However, for one of the ListView items, when it's selected, I want to increment count by 2.  How do I do this?  If I put:

```
        if (_criteria.SelectedItem == listViewItem4)
            count += 2;
```

then count is incremented by 2 for every other selection I make provided listViewItem4 is checked.  Also, I want to decrement count by 1 for every ListViewItem I deselect (and decrement by 2 when listViewItem4 is deselected) but in the SelectionChanged event, it counts both selection and deselection, so I keep getting increments.  What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event, look at e.AddedItems and e.RemovedItems to see which items have been added/removed from the list. If listViewItem4 is in e.AddedItems, you know what has happened.

Comment: Thanks.  The code to get what I was looking for is here:

        private void _crit(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem lv in e.AddedItems)
            { 
                count++;
                if (e.AddedItems.Contains(listViewItem4))
                    count += 1;
            }

            foreach (ListViewItem lv in e.RemovedItems)
            { 
                count--;
                if (e.RemovedItems.Contains(listViewItem4))
                count -= 1;
            }

            textBox1.Text = "score is " + count;

        }